# sum elements of vector excluding the first element in Octave

Tags: octave

I want to sum the square of all elements in a vector except the first element of such vector in Octave.

I´ve tried:

```
sum(x(2)^2)
```

And

```
sum(x(2:end)^2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, you need to use an elementwise operator, i.e. `.^`

```
sum( x(2:end) .^ 2 )
```

What you were using ( `^` ) was the 'matrix power' operator.

Type `help power` and `help mpower` in your console for details.